# Is the GML debugger showing me values for the wrong object/sprite?

Tags: gml

When the player (the_guy_obj) collides with food (berry_obj) and hits enter, the berry plays an "eaten" animation and stops at the last frame.
At the same time, the player plays an "eating" animation, and, upon reaching the last frame, switches to a static sprite. The following is written in their collide events:

(under berry_obj)

```
hitEnter = keyboard_check_pressed(vk_enter); 

if(hitEnter) 
{
    sprite_index = br_ani;
}


if(image_index == 4)
{
   image_speed = 0;     
}
```

(under the_guy_obj)

```
if (wasHit == true) {


if (lastPressed_L) //checks if facing left
{
    sprite_index = eat_left;    
}
if (lastPressed_R) //checks if facing right
{
    sprite_index = eat_right;
}

if (lastPressed_D) //checks if facing down
{
    sprite_index = down_eat;
    
} 


if (lastPressed_U) //checks if facing up
{
    sprite_index = up_eat;
    
}


    

}
```

While I'm debugging, "sprite_index" and "image_speed" return the same values in both collision events.
In the actual game, it works just fine, each object changes to the sprite I set it to.
What's going on? Is it reading these values as the same? Is it switching back and forth when different events are triggered?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly: `sprite_index` returns the ID of the sprite, and `image_index` returns the frame of the current sprite. where `image_speed` returns the value you've set at the image sprite on how much interval is inbetween the sprites.

Perhaps by coincidence, the numbers you were comparing matched each other?